# Загрузка аватарок как в Вконтакте. Где можно найти пример?

Tags: jquery, javascript, вконтакте, php

Привет всем! 
Делаю сайт для практики на локалке.
И тут наступило время загрузок аватарок. Хочу сделать по типу загрузил фото -> выбрал область -> сохранил на сервер. Ну как в ВК. Нашел способы по выделению. JCrop и т.п. Но проблема в этих способах было в том что  если пользователь загрузил фотографию с размером `1980х1024` (ну большую короче) то в браузере появляется полоса прокрутки (внизу). В CSS исправил пару строк. Добавил `max-width: 600px;` (к примеру), но если выделить область и при сохранении сохраняется другая область. p.s надеюсь вы поняли.

или как на одноклассниках можно сделать. Короче есть ли какие-нибудь решения загрузок аватарок с проверкой на размеры?

Чтобы можно было выделить область фотографии и потом ее сохранить. Аватарки у меня на сайте `200х200px`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://rubaxa.github.io/jquery.fileapi/ — не ради рекламы (пока это только beta), просто на память не могу вспомнить подобных решений.

Comment: Вы бы не могли по подробнее объяснить как она работает? Я потратил 2 часа и не понял. Она сохраняет фотографию которую пользователь выделяет? P.s по подробнее пожалуйста. А так она пока что лучше чем остальные

Comment: Именно так, сохраняет именно то, что выделил юзер, если что пишите на ibnRubaXa@gmail.com помогу с интеграцией.

Comment: Написал вам на почту. Жду ответа.

Comment: @RubaXa, очень круто, плюсанул вам!)